# Notification script | from RSS to Email | Bash

Tags: bash, linux

This is a script that must send an email at each new article published on a specific website. Any suggestions or improvements to do?

```
SENDER_EMAIL="sender@example.com"
TO_EMAIL="myemail@example.com"
RSS_SITE="example.com/feed.xml"
CHECK_INTERVAL=10

while [ 1 ]; do

    LINK_ARTICLE=$(rsstail -i 1 -u $RSS_SITE -l -n 0 -1 | grep -oP "Link:+ \K.*")
    TITLE_ARTICLE=$(rsstail -i 1 -u $RSS_SITE -n 0 -1 | grep -oP "Title:+ \K.*")

    if [ "$LINK_ARTICLE" != "" ] && [ "$TITLE_ARTICLE" != "" ]; then
        echo "New article published on the site. TITLE: $TITLE_ARTICLE - LINK: $LINK_ARTICLE" | EMAIL="$SENDER_EMAIL"  mutt -s "Nuovo Articolo BDO" "$TO_EMAIL"
        echo "New article published on the site. TITLE: $TITLE_ARTICLE - LINK: $LINK_ARTICLE"
    fi

    sleep $CHECK_INTERVAL
done
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I see a number of things that may help you improve your code.

### Use "shebang" line

The [shebang](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/shebang) is the line at the beginning of a shell script that tells which program to use.  In this case, you probably want this:

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10376206/what-is-the-preferred-bash-shebang) for details.

### Consider using `cron` instead of `sleep`

If this is something you want to run automatically, consider running it as a cron tab instead of using `sleep` within the script.

### Include some comments

The program requires `rsstail`, `mutt` and `sleep` which is a requirement that should be documented in a comment.

### Be cautious about handing variables to programs

The `mutt` program, like many Linux programs, has a `--` option which specifies that no further options are on the command line.  This prevents the contents of `$TO_EMAIL` in a line like the following from being misinterpreted as a command line option.

```
mutt -s $TITLE -- $TO_EMAIL < $BODYTEXT
```

### Combine strings

The `echo` is used twice with an identical string.  An alternative approach is

```
TITLE="Nuovo Articolo BDO"
BODYTEXT="New article published on the site. TITLE: $TITLE_ARTICLE - LINK: $LINK_ARTICLE"
mutt -s $TITLE -- $TO_EMAIL < $BODYTEXT
echo $BODYTEXT
```

### Avoid creating extraneous variables

Instead of creating `SENDER_EMAIL`, you could just specify `EMAIL` and then the reassignment of the latter variable before `mutt` is called would not be necessary.

### Consider writing a portable script

By sticking closely with [Posix](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/contents.html) and avoiding [bashisms](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh) your code could run on many different kinds of systems, including recent versions of Ubuntu which don't use `bash`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your meticulously written answer. Can you please explain why you would consider cron job instead of sleep in this case? Thanks.

Comment: One of the principles used in Linux is that programs are designed to do just one thing well. Because `cron` is a standard Linux tool to automatically run software on a periodic basis, I would probably use it for this application rather than having an infinitely running script.

Comment: I don't know about that. I think cron is just a bloat when I can do the same thing with while loop and sleep - using the same principle - use while loop to repeat stuff - use sleep to pause b/w execution.

Comment: The odds are about 99.9% that your system is already running `cron` so I don't think it reasonably qualifies as bloat.  In any case, the advice was merely to *consider* its use.